# Horizontal border is missing in table border on page break on converting cshtml page to pdf

Tags: css, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I am printing a large report in pdf format including many tables but it does not contains horizontal cell borders in general.
For doing this, I have generated the report in `cshtml`, then passed it to pdf using [NRECO](http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx)

Now what happens is when my tables size is larger and when the page breaks in to another page then i am not getting horizontal line in my table.

But i want that Horizontal border in my table  when my page break in Pdf.Currently i have 1 long table on Page1 at the end and i am not getting horizontal border.

See below image:[Horizontal border problem in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfXTz.png)

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="width100percent">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th></th>
                                                ...
                                                ...
                                           </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                           <tr>
                                                <td></td>
                                                 <td></td>
                                                 <td></td>
                                                ...
                                                ...
                                           </tr>
                                        </tbody>
        </table
```

Comment: here is my css .border-table tr td {
                padding: 0 3px;
                font-size: 11px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                height: 18px;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-family: Calibri;
                border-left: 1px solid #000000;
                page-break-inside: avoid;
                page-break-after: auto;
            }

Comment: This issue occurs only on pdf generation, in Browser its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at your code and trying to reproduce your issue. From your CSS, you have the borders for the cell elements only on the left side so it seems incomplete to generate the sample image you included.

Here's an example of a built out HTML page based on your content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Horizontal border problem in table</title>
    <style>
        table.width100percent {
            width: 100%;
            border-width: 0;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        .border-table tr td {
            padding: 0 3px;
            font-size: 11px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            height: 18px;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-family: Calibri;
            border-left: 1px solid #000000;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
            page-break-after: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="border-table">
        <table class="width100percent">
```

...full document here: https://pastebin.com/MNuwWNYG

I also tried converting it at [NReco](https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx) but as indicated above there are no horizontal borders to work with. The generated PDF looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCuv0.jpg